# SerialDataReceivedEventHandler with C# and PLC (not triggering event)

Tags: c#, serial-port, plc, modbus

I've gotten my PLC to communicate with my C# application using nModBus, but right now I'm reading all of the PLC inputs constantly by running through a for loop.

I want to design my code so that only when a piece of data is received through the serial port, then it will trigger the for loop to read through each input and determine which input in particular is high.

Here is what I have. I have set breakpoints and my code never even enters the DataReceivedHandler method. I am manually turning on the PLC inputs high (using a jumper wire). Any suggestions or comments?

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    static class Program
    {

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 38400;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.Odd;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        IModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(mySerialPort);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    public static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)

    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
```

Comment: Everybody always gets the Handshake wrong.  If you use None then you *must* set the RtsEnable and DtrEnable properties to *true* yourself.  And you surely have to give the PLC a reason to tell you about an input, they rarely volunteer it by themselves.

Comment: Hey Hans, I actually did set them to true in a previous script but it made no difference....I will try to do it again though.

Comment: also what do you mean "you have to give the PLC a reason to tell you" isn't that what the SerialDataReceivedEventHandler is doing for me? Forgive my ignorance, but you've commented on my posts in the past and I can tell you definitely know what you're talking about.

Comment: The normal protocol is master-slave.  You are the master, the PLC only slaves away when you tell it what to do.  It is otherwise just busy doing its normal job, executing the ladder logic.  So you'd have to send a "read input" command, only then will it send a response back.  And then of course your DataReceived event handler will fire.  Maybe it has a "tell me about changes without me asking for it" command, it isn't very common.  Look in the manual or ask the PLC manufacturer for support.

Comment: Gotcha, and yes I am using a readinput command (which is not in the script above), but not looking at the communication correctly.thank you for taking the time to share Hans!

Comment: Hi Hans, So I solved that issue...but now I need to dig deeper...I only want my readinput command to execute once the master(CPU) gets a signal from the PLC input. So the scenario is, when the operator presses a pushbutton on the PLC input, then it will trigger the readinput command on the cpu. As I write this, I am wondering if this is even possible considering my setup, would I now have to make my PLC the master for this to happen?

Comment: Try to add this line code bellow mySerialPort.DataReceived event: mySerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold = MINIMUM_DATA_LENGTH; mySerialPort.Open();   And also add this line code on top of DataReceivedHandler(): Thread.Sleep(RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);

Comment: MINIMUM_DATA_LENGTH is the minimum length of the data to be received by the serial port, eg 10 for 10 chars. And RECEIVE_TIMEOUT is the time it takes to read the data, eg 500 for 500 milisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Have your PC be the Master, but poll the event.  When that is TRUE, THEN do the "bulk" comm, then have your PC/master reset the "event".

I would make this "event" be a separate "communication event" from the actual UI one.  Make it be the "CommEvent", have the PLC set it (when the actual event occurs), and the PC/Master clear it once it finishes the bulk comm.

```
Read CommEvent
if CommEvent is TRUE
  Do BulkReads
  Clear CommEvent
```

Comment: Hey Franji, that is what I'm doing at the moment, but for that to work I need to continually poll the unit (so basically polling all the time). I think the PLC needs to be the master so that it can poll the PC when it has a data packet to be read.